# EF Core Migrations when context and entities are in different projects

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am running EF core 2 and I have my `DbContext`(s) in a data project.  That used to have the entities in the projects as well.  I moved the entities to another project now the property changes on the entities are not being recognized when I run `add-migration` on that context of those changed entities.

Do I need to do something different when the entities are in a different project then the context?

Comment: See if this helps. [Migrations with multiple projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects)

Comment: @PaoloGo  I can try to follow that logic with entities instead of migrations